# Displaying users in query result if they have no posts?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bot which collects activity from certain users and logs posts they make on one of my websites.  I have a list of moderators on this website and I would like to use MySQL to return information about their activity.  At the moment, I do the following:

```
SELECT count( num ) AS posts, username
FROM `logs`
WHERE username
IN (
'username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4', 'username5', 
)
AND FROM_UNIXTIME( epoch )
BETWEEN "2015-05-26"
AND "2015-05-29"
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY posts DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Some sample output from the above query:

```
username1 100
username2 50
username3 25
```

What I want to output:  How do I do this?

```
username1 100
username2 50
username3 25
username4 0
username5 0
```

Table structure:

```
num (int, key)
username (varchar)
epoch (varchar) 
msg (varchar)
```

Comment: I don;'t think it is a duplicate.  I'm inputting the users names manually since they change all the time; they are not part of another table.

Comment: Then I don't think you can accomplish the task the way you want to. If 'user1' doesn't have any posts, you don't have any record of 'user1' to return with a count of 0.

Comment: Since I'm supplying the list of users, is it maybe possible to perhaps use union select to append usernames to my query with posts=0 if they are already not there?

Comment: Maybe. Can you add a few rows of sample data to the question, and your expected results? I can tinker with it. Also, I'm retracting my close vote if you want to remove that comment from your question.

Comment: Yes, I changed my question.  Hopefully it is more understandable now.

Comment: Could you please add the table schema for the logs table?

Comment: You need to provide the `users` table. To return users that doesn't have any post, we need to join to `users` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `IFNULL` function that I think applies in this case

```
SELECT IFNULL(count( num ),0) AS posts, username
FROM `logs` ...
```

If the value of the count is null the posts will return 0

---

MySQL has some limitations that make queries like this particularly hard. What's hard is creating a temporary list of usernames that you need to join to make your query work

There is only one way that I know to do this. It involves storing the data in a temporary table and then querying with that table.

```
CREATE temporary table temp_users (name VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO temp_users (name) VALUES('username 1'),('username 2'),('username 3');

SELECT count( num ) AS posts, temp_username.username
FROM temp_username LEFT JOIN `logs` ON logs.username=temp_username.username
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME( epoch )
  BETWEEN "2015-05-26" AND "2015-05-29"
  GROUP BY username
  ORDER BY posts DESC
  LIMIT 0 , 30)
```

Here's an example that's been simplified http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc4ef1/11/0

The table is deleted at the end of the session

Comment: Also a `COALESCE(count(num),0) AS posts, username` in MySql. I use `COALESCE` instead of `IFNULL`, but honestly cannot remember why. Fairly sure they both work in this case.

Comment: `COALESCE` is better because it picks up the first not null value, so you can have `COALESCE(count(num),count(num)+1,0)` and it will pick up the zero. But apart from that they are largely the same

Comment: This doesn't work.  I think it is because It doesn't return null if the user has not posted anything, rather, it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Could you please add your  table structure to the question or some relevant columns and basic data. Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood